How to colour all the stratum specifically in R with ggalluvial?
Here is my data frame:
library(ggalluvial)
allu1 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~transitionState_PB,  ~DC_PIB, ~transitionState_PI, ~Freq,
             "BATF3",   "BATF3",                 "PI",    2,
             "BATF3",      "PB",                 "PI",    1,
             "BATF3",     "PIB",                 "PI",    1,
             "BATF3",   "BATF3",               "PU.1",    1,
             "BATF3",     "PIB",               "PU.1",    1,
             "BATF3",   "BATF3",            "unbound",    1,
                "PB",    "IRF8",               "IRF8",    4,
                "PB",      "PI",               "IRF8",    2,
                "PB",   "BATF3",                 "PI",    7,
                "PB",      "IB",                 "PI",    2,
                "PB",    "IRF8",                 "PI",    7,
                "PB",      "PB",                 "PI",   10,
                "PB",      "PI",                 "PI",   10,
                "PB",     "PIB",                 "PI",  232,
                "PB",    "PU.1",                 "PI",  121,
                "PB", "unbound",                 "PI",   80,
                "PB",   "BATF3",               "PU.1",    4,
                "PB",      "PB",               "PU.1",    6,
                "PB",     "PIB",               "PU.1",    8,
                "PB",    "PU.1",               "PU.1",   4)

Here is my code:
plot <- ggplot(data = allu1,
               aes(axis1 = transitionState_PB, axis2= DC_PIB, axis3= transitionState_PI,y = Freq)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = DC_PIB)) +
  geom_stratum(aes(fill= DC_PIB)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:3, labels = c("transitionState_PB","DC_PIB","transitionState_PI"))+
  geom_text(stat = "stratum",
            aes(label = after_stat(stratum)), size=2.6) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = PIBcol, name = c("transitionState_PB","DC_PIB","transitionState_PI"))+labs(x = colnames(allu1[, -4]), y = "Frequency") + 
  ggtitle("Loops vs peaks in loops common to- PB, PI & PIB") + theme_bw() +   xlab("From Tranition states to PIB") +         
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        title = element_text(size = 12), 
        legend.text = element_text(size = 10),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=8),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=8))

plot

I want to colour each axis with the following criteria
PIBcol <- c("PU.1" = "#4C0099", "BATF3" = "#994C00", "IRF8" = "#006600","PB" = "#FFB266", "PI" = "#66B2FF", "IB" = "#FFE60A", "PIB" = "#CC0088","unbound" = "#A0A0A0")
PBcol <- c("PU.1" = "#4C0099", "BATF3" = "#994C00", "PB" = "#FFB266", "unbound" = "#A0A0A0")
PBcol <- c("PU.1" = "#4C0099", "IRF8" = "#006600", "PI" = "#66B2FF","unbound" = "#A0A0A0")

But I don't find any examples on how to do it. Any help is very helpful.

Okay, I think I figured this out.
So, I first convert my df to lodes format like this,
df_lodes <- to_lodes_form(as.data.frame(allu1),
                          axes = 1:2,
                          id = rownames(allu1))

Then I do this,
ggplot(df_lodes, 
                aes(x = x, stratum = stratum, alluvium = df_lodes$`rownames(allu1)`,
                    fill = stratum, label = stratum, y = Freq)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = PIBcol) +
  geom_flow(stat = "flow", knot.pos = 1/4, aes.flow = "forward",
            color = "gray") + 
  geom_stratum() +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum",
            aes(label = after_stat(stratum)), size=2.6) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  ggtitle("Transition State analysis") + theme_bw() +   xlab("TF transition") +         
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        title = element_text(size = 12), 
        legend.text = element_text(size = 10),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=8),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=8))
    ```
And this works.

